# Binomial Distribution with constants

Tags: probability

A binomial random variable X has probability distribution function ${P(x) = k  (\frac{3}{4})^x (\frac{1}{4})^{3-x}}$ where x = 0, 1, 2, 3 and *k* is a constant.

The book said *k* is $\frac{8}{5}$. I'm confused because I thought since it was a binomial distribution problem it would be $4 \choose3$ because there's four sample spaces and the *r* value is 3.

Comment: sample space has four points 0,1,2,3. but here combinations are k=(3cx).

Comment: No binomial here. Who told you there was? (And the answer k=8/5 is correct.)

Comment: @SA-255525 Please, no invalid edits.

Comment: @Did According to Binomial Distribution P(x)=(3cx)(3/4)^x (1/4)^3-x , for x=0,1,2,3. That was what I was hinting at. And yes the answer  k=8/5 is correct.

Comment: @SA-255525, The OP said that his/her book said $k$ is $\frac85$.  You claim that it said $3\choose x$.  How do you know this?  What book was the OP using?

Comment: @Joel Reyes Noche, I did not claim this, I just edited the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "the $r$ value"? If it were a Binomial distribution with parameters $n,p$, then $k$ would be $\binom{n}{x}$. Since you are told that $k$ is constant and does not depend on $x$, then you find its value by normalizing. More precisely, it is necessary for

$$
1=P(0)+P(1)+P(2)+P(3),
$$

which you can rewrite as

$$
\frac1k=\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^0\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3+\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^1\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^1+\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^3\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^0=\frac{40}{64}=\frac{5}{8}.
$$